# Measure Voltage (Divide) on a current source

Tags: current-source, voltage-measurement, comparator

I need to use a constant current source 20mA, the current flows through multiple diodes and resistors which are in series.
The resistor value can vary from 0 to 1.6k and also a possibility of Open.

[image: Basic Circuit Diagram]

As the measuring device can read only upto 10V(Not multimeter, it is a 10V Analog Input Card), and at present 20mA*1.6k=32V+(diode drop). Hence I need to reduce this voltage before passing to the measuring device.

1. Is there a simple way to do it?(Current Source is a must)
2. To protect Open Condition of the resistor is a Zener Diode Sufficient?

Comment: The ratio is something like V=IR ... But I am not entirely sure because this is just an Electrical site

Comment: Ok I get it you are a genius. I have a problem since there are diodes in series to the resistor, so I take the ratio of the Voltage and Current, I manipulate the Output. The constant current source is a must for me.

Comment: Are you trying to measure the resistance of R? Why would you want to put a resistor in parallel with R? Use a digital multi-meter to measure the voltage if you are worried that your voltmeter's resistance is going to affect the measurement.

Answer (score 2):

To measure the voltage across the resistor under test, you just measure it, like by connecting a voltmeter across it.

With 20 mA thru the resistor under test and 10 V max, the highest resistance you can measure is 500 Ω.  Even a crappy voltmeter will have so much higher resistance that it won't distort the measurement.  For example, let's say you're measuring a 500 Ω resistor.  According to your spec, it has 20 mA going thru it, so 10 V across it.  A 1 MΩ (that's really crappy) voltmeter will draw 10 µA, which will distort the measurement by (10 µA)/(20 mA) = 0.05%.  Is your voltmeter good to 0.05%?  I didn't think so.

### Added

You have now shown a schematic.  The voltmeter is in the wrong place.  Put it directly across the resistor under test.

Comment: Hello, I've edited my question. When I read it even I could not Understand it myself. Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, it is not a voltmeter (but a 10V analog Input Card). And I have to read the voltage from the source side as the resistor would be 160m away from the source.

Comment: OMG!!! A simple voltage divider was sufficient to do the job. I was worried about the overvoltage which it would create during open condition,